# Linearly independent over $F_p$ to $Q$

Tags: linear-algebra, number-theory

Let $v_1, . . . , v_m$ be vectors with $n$ $(0,1)$-entries. Prove that if these vectors are linearly independent over $\mathbb{F}_p$ for some prime number $p$ then they are linearly independent over $\mathbb{Q}$.

My attempt:

If we have a $n$ by $m$ matrix $A$ whose column vectors are $v_1, . . . , v_m$, and they are linearly independent over the field $\mathbb{F_p}$ where p is a prime number. That implies $det(A)$ mod $p \neq 0$.

Then in the field $\mathbb{Q}$, there is also $det(A)$ mod $p \neq 0$, so the column vectors are linearly independent over the field $\mathbb{Q}$.

I am not sure it is ok.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Please include your attempts at the problem; otherwise the question is likely to be closed soon for lack of context.

Comment: I considered forming a matrix $A = [v_1, ..., v_m]$, and think about its congruence modular(for example, A=I, mod p) matrix to compute its rank, then I have no idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose that the vectors are $\Bbb Q$-linearly dependent. Clearing denominators, obtain a non-trivial $\Bbb Z$-linear combination of these vectors that equals zero. Now consider the residues modulo $p$.

Comment: Here are the steps: (1) assume $q_1v_1+q_2v_2+...+q_mv_m = 0$ where not all $q$ are zero. (2)multiply common denominators and divise their g.c.d, which implies that their new g.c.d is 1. (3)however, consider $(q_1 mod p)v_1+(q_2 mod p)v_2+...+(q_m mod p)v_m = 0$, according to the assumption(linearly independent in $\mathbb{F_p}$), q_i mod p = 0, i=1, ...m (4)contradciting to "their g.c.d is 1". (5)thus, they are linearly independent in $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: Indeed, you got it :)

Comment: thanks a lot！(>.<)