# Prove that if vector system is linear independent over $Z_p$ then this system is linear independent over $Q$

Tags: linear-algebra

Prove that if integer vector system is linear independent over $Z_p$ ($p$ is prime) then this system is linear independent over $\mathbb{Q}$.

I understand how to solve this problem (saw this solution: [Linearly independent over $F_p$ to $Q$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3997526/linearly-independent-over-f-p-to-q))
but there's one point that seems unclear to me. When we transform $q_1v_1+q_2v_2+...+q_mv_m = 0$ into $(q_1 \bmod p)v_1+(q_2 \bmod p)v_2+...+(q_m \bmod p)v_m = 0$ , do the vectors remain the same? (Do I have to take modulo of vector coordinates?) Moreover, there's one thing in the definition of linear space that I don't understand: if $q_i \in Z_p$ and $v_i \in Z^n$. Does the coordinate of $q_iv_i$ belong to $Z_p$ or $Z$ ? And one more thing: in this problem only $Z_p$ is being discussed ($p$ is prime), what about other cases ($p$ is not prime), we don't mention them only because $Z_p$, when $p$ is not prime, is not a field?